# Change the ID attribute of a <span> when user selectes a new option from list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to update the id attribute of the `<span>` below when a user changes an option in the `<select>`, but really struggling.

```
<h5 class="wide">
    Image to show:
    <span id="image-preview-6385" class="colorbox-preview">preview</span>
</h5>
<select id="agri-image-id" class="wide image-select" name="middle_header_service[agriculture][image_id]">
    <option value="-1">No image for this service</option>
    <option value="6176">Brick houses (150x80)</option>
    <option value="6175">Brick houses (little ... (150x53)</option>
</select>
```

My code so far -

```
jQuery('.image-select').change(function(e){

    selected_id = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(this).prev('h5 span.colorbox-preview').attr('id', 'image-preview-'+selected_id);

});
```

I can get a response when I use `alert(jQuery(this).prev('h5')).attr('id'))`, but anything beyond that comes back as `undefined`. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Your DOM traversal is incorrect. `.prev()` returns the previous sibling of the currently selected element(s), optionally filtering based on a selector. In this case, your previous element is a `<h5>` element. You can't use `.prev()` to select an element that's **inside** the previous element, like your `<span>` is. You'll need to select the previous element, then search for the matching element inside it using `.find()`, as thecodeparadox shows in his answer.

Comment: @Anthony Grist, actually, you can use prev for this. `$(this).prev($('span.colorbox-preview', 'h5'))`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've never seen that usage before, and it's not supported by the documentation - is this yet another undocumented jQuery feature?

Comment: @Anthony Grist all jQuery selectors accept multiple parameters. Basically, `$('span.colorbox-preview', 'h5')` will find all span.colorbox-preview elements that match within an h5. If you used multiple obejcts, such as `, 'h5', 'h5.wide', 'h4', 'p.talk'` etc, it would selec the `span.colorbox-preview` from inside any of those elements that it matched.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That I know about - I meant passing a jQuery object containing elements matching a selector to `.prev()`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - Thanks for the tip, that was a feature of jQuery I was unaware of, and one that I'm sure will be very useful in the future.

@AnthonyGrist - `.find()` does appear to be what I needed, although I used it in conjunction with `.prev()` for this. I'll hopefully remember this lesson next time I am doing something similar! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any one of following should work:

```
jQuery(this) // select box itself
         .prev('h5.wide') // prev h5 with class wide
         .find('span.colorbox-preview')  // search for span within h5
         .attr('id', 'image-preview-'+selected_id); // change id
```

OR

```
jQuery('h5.wide') // h5 itself
    .find('span.colorbox-preview').attr('id', 'image-preview-'+selected_id);
```

Comment: You can filter the selection of the element directly within the prev, you don't need to use find as another selector. `$(this).prev($('span.colorbox-preview', 'h5'))`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `$('span.colorbox-preview', 'h5')` will internally called the `find()` method. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @thecodeparadox - Thank you, this worked for me first time (your first method)!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ujP4L/1/)**

```
jQuery('.image-select').change(function(e) {    
    selected_id = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(this).siblings('h5').children('span.colorbox-preview').attr('id', 'image-preview-' + selected_id);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

WHen you traverse you can only go one direction at a  a time. You are trying go to a sibling using `prev()` and within the same selector, look inside the sibling which doesn't work.

```
 /* traverse to sibling*/ 
jQuery(this).prev('h5')     
/* sibling H5 is now current object, look within it*/
.find('span.colorbox-preview')
/* span now current object, do something with it*/
.attr('id', 'image-preview-'+selected_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I use, someone just beat you to the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the id of an element is not supposed to change, because it make refering to this element by JS tricky.

I assume you are using a CSS background-image linked to the `<span>` id, but you could use an `<img>` element and change its src attribute, and hide the image when selected_id is -1

**HTML:**

```
<h5 class="wide">
    Image to show:
    <img id="image-preview" class="colorbox-preview" src="blank.gif">
</h5>
<select id="agri-image-id" class="wide image-select" name="middle_header_service[agriculture][image_id]">
    <option value="-1">No image for this service</option>
    <option value="6176">Brick houses (150x80)</option>
    <option value="6175">Brick houses (little ... (150x53)</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery('.image-select').change(function(e){
    selected_id = jQuery(this).val();
    image = jQuery("#image-preview");

    if (selected_id == -1) {
        image.attr("src", "blank.gif");
    else {
        image.attr("src", "preview_" + selected_id + ".gif");
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree that really the ID of an element should not change, but in this case my hands are tied with regards to the name of the images. I like your suggestion of using `src` though, and although I can't put the full image name in there, putting the ID in there should work...